# How to list apache afterwards installed modules?

Tags: apache-2.4

Can you figure out a simple command how to list apache afterwards installed modules?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use your package manager to find out which modules are installed by default:

```
rpm -ql httpd | grep modules

/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_access_compat.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_actions.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_alias.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_allowmethods.so
/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_asis.so
...
```

When you query which other packages are installed that depend on the `httpd` package (requires the `yum-utils` package to be installed) the list should also include any additional Apache httpd modules:

```
repoquery --whatrequires --installed --recursive httpd

mod_ssl-1:2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64
php-0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.x86_64
roundcubemail-0:1.1.10-1.el7.noarch
```